# Creating a directed adjacency matrix from a dataframe with many columns

Tags: python, r, graph-theory, igraph, adjacency-matrix

I want to create a directed adjacency matrix from data like this:

| x1 | x2 | x3 | x4 | x5 | x6 | x7 | x8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 22 | 22 | 22 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 23 |

Where the columns represent states in time.

The adjacency matrix should reflect the following logic:

For the column x1:
**1** should go to the 3 rows in column x2,

**22** should go to the 3 rows in column x2,

**3** should go to the 3 rows in column x2

For the column x2: The same pattern going to column x3.
And this for all columns. So it's like linking each element in a given column to all elements of the following column, and so on.

The output should be a matrix with columns and rows N x N (where N in the number of unique values in the whole matrix) and... well, an adjacency matrix.

This dataframe is just a sample, the one I have to use has hundreds of columns.

For these 8 columns, the output should resemble something like this:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 22 | 23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 22 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 23 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

This is a representation of how the graph should look like. (edited)

[image]

I've been trying to make it work, but am really lost by now...
TIA

P.S. I'm working with R but Python could also work.

Comment: Still unclear of the output. Can you show the first 5 rows of the output

Comment: Why is there a 6 in the top right cell of the output?  What does 6 represent?  In any case, the leading diagonal of an adjacency matrix should be zero ( nodes are not connected to themselves ).

Comment: A diagonal element different than 0 represents a loop. I understand your question because loops are usually represented differently, but in this case the 6 means to represent that value 1 is connected to itself 6 times.
It's possible I'm messing up a bit in the structure, but this is what the paper I'm following describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the adjacency matrix is the thing you are after. I guess it should be the summary info of transitions. You can try the base R code below (without `igraph`)

```
d <- do.call(
  rbind,
  apply(
    embed(seq_along(df), 2),
    1,
    function(k) {
      expand.grid(
        setNames(
          df[rev(k)],
          c("from", "to")
        )
      )
    }
  )
)
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(d)))
table(list2DF(lapply(d, factor, level = lvls)))
```

which gives

```
    to
from 1 2 3 5 22 23
  1  6 3 7 2  2  1
  2  1 2 2 0  0  1
  3  6 3 7 2  2  1
  5  2 1 2 1  0  0
  22 3 0 3 1  2  0
  23 0 0 0 0  0  0
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x1 = c(1L, 22L, 3L), x2 = c(1L, 22L, 3L), x3 = c(1L, 
22L, 3L), x4 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), x5 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), x6 = c(1L,
3L, 2L), x7 = 1:3, x8 = c(2L, 3L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

Comment: you're right. I became a bit confused with the article's description of this part of the algorithm. In case I wanted a real adjacency matrix (so in the drawing, each node would be unique, but with the number in each circle as an attribute), how could I approach the coding?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(~factor(x1, unique(c(x1, values)))+values, cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1]))))
   1 2 3 5 22 23
1  6 1 0 0  0  0
22 0 1 4 0  2  0
3  0 1 3 2  0  1
5  0 0 0 0  0  0
2  0 0 0 0  0  0
23 0 0 0 0  0  0


xtabs(~x1+x, transform(reshape(df, names(df)[-1], dir='long', sep=''), x1 = factor(x1, unique(c(x,x1)))))
    x
x1   1 2 3 5 22 23
  1  6 1 0 0  0  0
  22 0 1 4 0  2  0
  3  0 1 3 2  0  1
  5  0 0 0 0  0  0
  2  0 0 0 0  0  0
  23 0 0 0 0  0  0

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   mutate(x1 = factor(x1, unique(unlist(.)))) %>%
   pivot_longer(-x1) %>%
   xtabs(~x1+value,.) %>%
   as.data.frame.matrix()

   1 2 3 5 22 23
1  6 1 0 0  0  0
22 0 1 4 0  2  0
3  0 1 3 2  0  1
5  0 0 0 0  0  0
2  0 0 0 0  0  0
23 0 0 0 0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may misunderstand how an adjacency matrix works.

The matrix contains Boolean values ( true or false )

The nodes should be indexed 1,2,3,4, ...

If there is a link from node 1 to node 2, then the cell in row 2, column 1 will be true.

Let's index your first two columns like this

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

So node 1 is linked to nodes 4,5, and 6

and the adjacency matrix looks like this

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
1 
2 
3
4 1 1 1
5 1 1 1
6 1 1 1
```

Comment: I understand your reasoning (tho it's possible to have 0,1 and 2 right?).
In that case I need to build a structure like what the picture shows, with node attributes equal to what the numbers are showing.

Comment: The cells in the adjacency matrix indicate whether or not there is a link between two nodes.  So the value can be false or true ( == blank or 1 ).  A value of 2 has no meaning.

Comment: Yes yes forget what I'm saying about that (it's been a long day). What I meant was that diagonals can be non-0.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the dataframe of `@ThomasisCoding`.

```
  structure(list(x1 = c(1L, 22L, 3L), x2 = c(1L, 22L, 3L), x3 = c(1L, 
  22L, 3L), x4 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), x5 = c(1L, 3L, 5L), x6 = c(1L,
  3L, 2L), x7 = 1:3, x8 = c(2L, 3L, 23L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
  -3L))
```

The first alternative is to combine all nodes without regard to time (x1, x2, ...).

```
m1 <- formatC(as.matrix(df), width = 2, format = "d", flag = "0")
```

Output.

```
      x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8  
 [1,] "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "01" "02"
 [2,] "22" "22" "22" "03" "03" "03" "02" "03"
 [3,] "03" "03" "03" "05" "05" "02" "03" "23"
```

Alternative (II) takes into account the time of observation.

```
m2 <- 
  rbind(
  c1=paste(m1[1,], names(df), sep="_"),
  c2=paste(m1[2,], names(df), sep="_"),
  c3=paste(m1[3,], names(df), sep="_")
  )
```

Output.

```
  [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]   
c1 "01_x1" "01_x2" "01_x3" "01_x4" "01_x5" "01_x6" "01_x7" "02_x8"
c2 "22_x1" "22_x2" "22_x3" "03_x4" "03_x5" "03_x6" "02_x7" "03_x8"
c3 "03_x1" "03_x2" "03_x3" "05_x4" "05_x5" "02_x6" "03_x7" "23_x8"
```

Expand.grid() combines all occurrences at x(i) with x(i+1) for i = 1 through 7.
Choose m1 or m2 depending on scenario at hand.

```
mc <- m1
mmm <- c()
for (i in seq(ncol(m1)-1) ) { 
  mmm <- rbind(mmm, expand.grid(x = mc[, i], y = mc[, i + 1])) 
}
table(mmm)
g   <- graph_from_data_frame(mmm, directed=FALSE)
plot(g)
g[]
```

Output (I). Check this output with `table(mmm)`.

```
6 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   01 22 03 05 02 23
01  6  2  7  2  3  1
22  3  2  3  1  .  .
03  6  2  7  2  3  1
05  2  .  2  1  1  .
02  1  .  2  .  2  1
23  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

Output (II).

```
24 x 24 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
   [[ suppressing 24 column names ‘01_x1’, ‘22_x1’, ‘03_x1’ ... ]]
                                                     
01_x1 . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
22_x1 . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
03_x1 . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
01_x2 . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
22_x2 . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
03_x2 . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
01_x3 . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
22_x3 . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
03_x3 . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . . . . .
01_x4 . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . .
03_x4 . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . .
05_x4 . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . . . . .
01_x5 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . .
03_x5 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . .
05_x5 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . . . . .
01_x6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . .
03_x6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . .
02_x6 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1 . . .
01_x7 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1
02_x7 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1
03_x7 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 1
02_x8 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
03_x8 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
23_x8 . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```